# What does "player != ANY (SELECT player FROM Member)" return?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, query, syntax

I have this table and these queries

[image]
[image]

I've run both queries with these results:
[image]

I'm confused about the line with the WHERE clause in each query. Specifically that ALL and that ANY. I understand what ALL and ANY do. Shouldn't they return a boolean value?

This syntax is confusing me. It would make sense that the first query verifies if player is different from ALL the players of Member, which would return 0 rows, and the second query verifies that player is different from ANY player of Member, which would be true if there was at least one player in the table that was different from player.
Is this correct and is the syntax just a bit different from usual? If I remember right the condition should be in the parentheses and not outside of them.

Comment: please don't post images that contain text or dat, also a [mre] would be good

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, it wll return all rows.

The condition

```
SELECt * FROM member WHERe vname <> ANY (SELECT vname FROM member)
```

check for every row, it the value in not equal to `ANY` value in the `SELECT`, so if only **one** is not equal to the value it compares to, the condition is met, so that it is true for every column as long you `SELECT` **all** rows from the table.